# Undefined function or variable without global variable in matlab

Tags: matlab

Now I'm trying to study the MATLAB's function and making a simple function the name as aaa(), But I've got the an error message as Undefined function or variable.

I can't understand it.

what am I supposed to do to resolve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udnt6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You named you function test1.m So that is how you have to call it at the command prompt.

```
test1(z)
```

You should name the M-file the same name as the function declaration.  [See Documentation Here.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/calling-functions.html#bsoaz58-1)  So either save the m-file as aaa.m or change the first line to `function y = test1(x)`

You will notice in the editor that `aaa` is underlined in red.  That is Matlab warning you that the names do not match.

Comment: I get it. thanks.  the function name should be the same as M file.